# jQuery $.ajax post value is empty

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Why my code post value is empty? 
I try foreach echo key and value, but it show "0 Array"

my code like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#btn_attend").click(function() {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'ajax.attend.php',
                data: ' { user_attend: "<?php echo ($auth_user->is_attend()) ? "true" : "false"; ?>" }',
                beforeSend: function() {
                    ...
                },
                success: function() {
                    ...
                },
                error: function() {
                    ...
                }
            });
            return false;
        } else {
            ...
        }
    });

});
```

and developer tools show post value

[developer tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lYlVJ.jpg)

ajax.attend.php code like:

```
<?php

echo "POST=".strip_tags($_POST['user_attend']);

if(empty($_POST)==false)
  {
     ...
  }
  else
  {
      echo "error:: empty post.";
  }
?>
```

show:

POST=
error:: empty post.

Comment: `userattend != user_attend`

Comment: user_attend != userattend; check your var name

Comment: oh! it is strip_tags($_POST['user_attend']) not $_POST['userattend']

Answer (score 2):

Since you want to sent the value as a parameter key/value pair, `data` should be an object not a string, also need to fix the parameter name to `userattend`

```
data:  { userattend: "<?php echo ($auth_user->is_attend()) ? true : false; ?>" }
```

Comment: Ok! I ref jQuery API Documentation,
data
Type: PlainObject or String or Array http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

I try this code

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value){
    echo "$key => $value";
    if(is_array($value)){ //If $value is an array, print it as well!
        printArray($value);
    }  
}
```

it show this

```
{_user_attend:_"true"_} =>
```

so it not post value.

I edit this, it work!

```
data: { user_attend: "<?php echo ($auth_user->is_attend()) ? "true" : "false"; ?>" },
```

> delete this " **'** "

thank you guys!